# Do I need to use Artificial Grass Tape brand?

Tags: adhesive, landscaping, backyard

If I buy one brand of the artificial grass and I need to seam the connections, can I use the grass tapes sold at the local home improvement store? As I need to grab something as I go and only "SYNLawn 12-in x 20-ft Black Artificial Grass Tape" is available. Will it have adhesive problem or chemical reaction issues over time?

Comment: TIL there is tape for grass.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Probably not, but if you might want or need support from the manufacturer then you should probably buy theirs....

Comment: This seems to be asking about product recommendations... generally, check the [product reviews](http://www.lowes.com/pd/SYNLawn-12-in-x-20-ft-Black-Artificial-Grass-Tape/3561792) as they are the best source for that kind info, and it's a good place to post your own review. It gets high stars, but one comment mentions that it's not actually tape... not sticky. It's a weed barrier.

Comment: I am just asking in general if artificial grass tape is generic / universal or each company is doing things differently. The reason is that none of the manufacturers said anything about you have to use their tape / adhesive. As a matter of fact, some don't even sell the thing but just the grass.